# Python. How to print a certain part of a line after it had been "re.searched" from a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Could you tell me how to print this part of the line only '\w+.226.\w.+' ?

Code

```
VSP = input("Номер ВСП (четыре цифры): ")

a = re.compile(r'\w+.226.\w.+'+VSP)
b=re.search(a, open('Sample.txt').read())
print (b.group())

Номер ВСП (четыре цифры): 1020
10.226.27.60    1020
```

After I have found the intended line associated with my variable "VSP" in the txt file, how can exclude it from output, printing the"10.226.27.60" only?

Comment: *always* use the generic Python tag

Comment: Do you really have to read in the entire file all at once?

Comment: Use a capture group around the part you want, `print(b.group(1))`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for `\w+\.226\.\w+` (notice the backslashes before the dots and the removed dot after the second `\w`)?

Comment: All I need is to get and then print an ip address  from a txt file .This ip address  is binded with a variable and placed in one line in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify your regex slightly to separate the trailing characters in the IP and the spaces that separate it from VSP. Adding a capture group will let you select the portion with just the IP address. The updated regex looks like this:

```
'(\d+\.226\.\S+)\s+' + VSP
```

`\S` (uppercase S) matches any non-whitespace, while `\s` (lowercase s) matches all whitespace. I replaced the first `\w` with the more specific `\d` (digits), and `.` (any character at all) with `\.` (actual period). The second `\w` is now `\S`, but you could use `\d+\.\d+` if you wanted to be more specific.

Using the first capture group will give you the IP address:

```
print(b.group(1))
```

If you are looking for a single IP address once, not compiling your regex is fine. Also, reading in a small file in its entirety is OK as long as the file is small. If either is not the case, I would recommend compiling the regex and going through the file line by line. That will allow you to discard most lines much faster than using a regex would do.

Comment: After all I've got another roadblock. When I got the intended ip address in b.group(1), how can I convert this ip address to integer? Im planning to subtract "1" from last octet getting 10.226.27.59 for another host .....

Comment: @user9100567. I think that is a completely different question. I'd recommend doing some quick googling before you post a question though, because i suspect it's been answered many times over by now. If you really can't find anything, ping me and I'll write an answer for you.

Comment: Man, my searching was unsuccesful. Could youhelp me with that  nevertheless ? Here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837122/converting-group-to-float-or-int-format

Comment: @user9100567. Looks like you got the answer you wanted :)

Comment: Yeah, man, and my script is already over! I'm a network engineer and just 3 days in a raw Im into Python. It's amazing =)

Comment: @user9100567. Yeah, it's a pretty great language. I switched to it from Java and C++ a couple of years ago, haven't ever looked back. Still love C though.

Answer (score -1):

I see you already have an answer.You can also try this regex if you were to separate the two groups by the whitespace:

```
import re

a = re.compile(r'(.+?)\s+(.+)') # edit: added ? to avoid
                                # greedy behaviour of first .+
                                # otherwise multiple spaces after the
                                # address will be caught into
                                # b.group(1), as per @Mad comment

b=re.search(a, '10.226.27.60    1020')
print (b.group(0))
print (b.group(1))
print (b.group(2))
```

or customize the first group regexp to your needs.

Edit:
This was not meant to be a proper answer but more of a comment wich I didn't think was readable as such; I am trying only to show group separation using regex, wich seems OP didn't know about or didn't use.
That is why I am not matching .226. because OP can do that. I also removed the file read part, which isn't needed for demonstration. Please read @Mad answer because its quite complete and in fact also shows how to use groups.

Comment: This is not at all what OP is doing

Comment: With greedy matching, the first `.+` will grab everything up to the last space. If there are more spaces than one separating the address and the number, this won't work.

Comment: You are right again @Mad. Just confirmed it by printing with repr(). Added a ? to solve that.

Comment: OP also never said anything about that being the only content on the line.

Comment: OP says: "This ip address is binded with a variable and placed in one line in the text file." Can't see the problem.