# Converting group() to float or int format

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a followup to [Python. How to print a certain part of a line after it had been "re.searched" from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47820803/2988730)

Here is the initial code, based on the accepted answer to the linked question:

```
import re

VSP = input("Номер ВСП (четыре цифры): ")

c = re.compile('(\d+\.226\.\S+)\s+\S+' + VSP)
Tunnel0_IP_VSP = re.search(c, open('OUS_IP.txt').read())
print (Tunnel1_IP_VSP.group(1))

Номер ВСП (четыре цифры): 1020
10.226.27.60
```

I was able to find the requested IP address in text file.

My goal is to somehow convert the string `"10.226.27.60"` to a format that would allow me to use it in mathematical formulas. For example, I want to get another address `"10.226.27.59"` by subtracting 1 from the last octet of the original address.

Comment: You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: Thats true, but I really need to resolve my problem as soon as possible and with your help I could learn much faster

Comment: You could split the strings by `.` and then the natural ordering of the resulting list of strings should be all you need...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is what I did in my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ipaddress` module for Python 3:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('10.226.27.60')
>>> ip - 1
IPv4Address('10.226.27.59')
```

The `IPv4Address` class allows for arithmetic operators

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#operators

Comment: Thats good, but I need something like that ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(Tunnel1_IP_VSP.group(1)). Its not possible in here.

Comment: @user9100567 why is it not possible here?

Comment: I apologize, that works and this is the quickest decision

Comment: The only potential inconvenience is that if you want to subtract `1` from the second octet, for example, you would have to do something like `ip - (1 << 16)`. I find this to be less convenient than doing `ip[1] -= 1`, as you would do in the list representation, but +1 regardless.

Comment: This site and you guys are amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could take the `string` (what you end up with):

```
s = "10.226.27.60"
```

and then `split` on `'.'` and use a `list-comprehension` to convert the parts to `integers`:

```
p = [int(i) for i in s.split('.')]
```

and then finally, subtract `1` from the last element:

```
p[-1] -= 1
```

to get `p` as:

```
[10, 226, 27, 59]
```

---

Note that if you want to display this list in the original `string` format, then you can use `join` with a `generator-expression`:

```
".".join(str(i) for i in p)
#"10.226.27.60"
```

Comment: Alternatively `'.'.join(map(str, p))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
string = "10.226.27.60".split(".")
number_list = [int(number) for number in string]
print(number_list)
```

[10, 226, 27, 60] you can calculate each element

convert back:

```
string_again = ".".join(str(number) for number in number_list)
print(string_again)
```

10.226.27.60